how to backup a recordset in Blazor Server with .net8 and TSQL
With Blazor Server and .NET6 I used to backup a recordset after editing by a TSQL script.
But with .NET8 this TSQL script is not possible anymore. ERROR URL: https://aka.ms/efcore-docs-sqlserver-save-changes-and-output-clause
My Question, what is the recomondation and the best way to backup a recordset (after edit) in a Blazor Server App?
many thanks for your support, marcel
To find out the best workaround to backup a recordset in Blazor!
